# Payley-Zygmund Inequality Application $Pr\left(|\sum_{i=1}^m y_i x_i | > \frac 1 2 \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^m {y_i}^2}\right) \ge K$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expectation

Assume x1, x2, x3, ..., xn are independent arbitrary signs such that Pr(xi=-1)=Pr(xi=1)=1/2.

Show a positive constant K exists s.t. for m ≥ 1 and y1, . . . , yn ∈ ℝ, the following is true:

$$\begin{equation*}
Pr\left(|\sum_{i=1}^m y_i x_i | > \frac 1 2 \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^m {y_i}^2}\right) \ge K
\end{equation*}$$

I think this has looks familiar with the Payley-Zygmund which states that:

$$Pr(X>θEX) \ge {(1 − θ)}^2 \frac {{E(X)}^2} {E(X^2)}$$

Do I have to replace θEX with $\frac 1 2 \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^m {y_i}^2}$? I am a little confused as in how to do the transformation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $K$ has to be independent of $m$ and the $y_i$'s, you cannot get this immediately from Paley -Zygmund. I have given a proof using CLT and UBP.

Comment: can you briefly explain what is clt and ubp thnk you

Comment: CLT is Central Limit Theorem, but I have edited my proof and CLT is no longer required. UBP stands for Uniform Boundedness Principle, a powerful tool from Functional Analysis. I cannot think of a proof without UBP.

Comment: got it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma

There exist a positive constant $c$ such that $E|\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i| \leq c \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{2}}$ for all choices of $m$ and $y_i$'s.

Assuming this for the moment take $X= \frac {|\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i|} {\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{2}}}$ and $\theta =\frac 1 {c}$ in Payley - Zygmund  to get the desired inequality. [ Just note that $X>1/2$ implies $X>(1/2)\theta EX$. I will leave the details here but feel free to ask for the details if necesssary].

To prove the lemma we need Uniform Boundedness Principle. Define linear maps $T_m:l^{2} \to L^{1}(P)$ by $T_m(\{y_n\})=\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i$. It is clear that these are continuous linear maps. We claim that for any fixed $\{y_n\} \in l^{2}$ $\sup_m ( E|\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i|)<\infty$. To prove this just note that the second moments of $\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i$ are bounded.Hence the first moments are also bounded.

Now we apply Uniform Boundedness Principle to conclude that   $\sup \{( E|\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_ix_i|):m\geq 1 ,\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{2}} \leq 1 \}<\infty$. This proves the lemma.

Comment: for the details part, if I substitue X into E(X)^2 and  E(X^2), then since E(X)^2 and  E(X^2) are both constants, the RHS will be constant as well, is that what you meant by the details? thanks

Comment: Yes. BTW, the lemma I have proved is one-half of a standard result called Khinchine's Inequalities. (Ref. p. 468 of 'Probability' by Shiryayev). If you are willing to accept this standard result then the answer to your question becomes very simple. I gave a proof of the lemma thinking that you may not be familiar with Khinchine's Inequalities.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Could you provide details,  don't see how the right hand side is constant